# Jade include file and pass model data

Tags: node.js, express, pug

I'm trying to learn Node/Jade and a few other JS-centric technologies all at once. I'm coming from a .NET MVC background so I'm used to being able to pass my entire model or properties of the model to partial files, which I separate out from my main view for the sake of reuse.

I have this simple route defined:

**index.js**

```
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('index', data);
});

var data = {
    title: 'This is the title',
    posts: [
        {
            firstname: 'Scott'
        },
        {
            firstname: 'John'
        }
    ]
}
```

**index.jade**

```
extends layout

block content
  section
    each p in posts
      include post ????? //How would I pass the "p" object to my include
```

**post.jade**

```
div.post
  p #{firstname}
```

So my question (also inline within the index.jade sample) is, **how do I pass the "p" object within my `each` loop to the include?** If that's not possible, what's the accepted approach with Jade for accomplishing something like this?

Sorry for the rookie question, just getting started with Jade/Express/Node!

Answer (score 2):

Figured it out.

**index.jade**

```
extends layout
include post

block content
  section
    each p in posts
      mixin post(p)
```

**post.jade**

```
mixin post(p)
  div.post
    p #{p.firstname}
```